# ks.test in spatstat package

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm trying to make ks.test on my data in spatstat package. I use ppp function to create my pattern  named ppp then when i try this code:

`ks.test(ppp,"x")`  as in the documentation it says object 'x' not found.

Then i try this:

`ks.test(ppp,data$XM)` it says: Error in order(w): type 'list' not avaible in 'orderVector1'

So I try with a function:

`fun <- function(x,y){(x+y)/x}`
`ks.test(ppp,fun)` and it says: Error in xi == xj: comparison of these types not implemented.

I need to use this fucntion but whatever i try following the documentation i don't find the solution.

Comment: Please provide some information about your data. We have no idea if you are passing the appropriate object types to the function. Code that indicates how you created the "ppp" and "data" objects would help as well as results of `str`. You are calling the incorrect function as well. You are after `kstest` or `cdf.test` not `ks.test`. Also, do you realize that these functions are for testing a point process model and not simply a ppp object? BTW, naming objects the same as existing functions (eg., ppp, data) can yield quite unexpected results.

Comment: In fact I have data set with coordinates `XM YM` I create ppp Object and call it `ppp` here to show you I use it at the good place.  Then i want to make Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of CSR  on my data. `kstest` isn't found by R  so maybe there is a package missing here. Following the documention we can use this kind of function on ppp object to test it. I don't have more information on my data. I want to test if my point are randomly or uniformly distributed and this is the solution I found.

Comment: A bit ago the spatstat library was split into multiple libraries to accommodate CRAN standards. As such, older online tutorials may not reflect these changes. I believe that `kstest` and `cdf.test` are now in the spatstat.core library. To address your question of dispersion, you may want to look at the empty space `Fest` or `Gest` statistic or the K function `Kest`.

Comment: When I install my package and import it, I get spatstat.core too. I find `cdf.test` but still impossible to find `kstest`, it shows me `ks.test`. When I use `Quadrat.test` or `kstest` it test the CSR of my data isn't it ? So I don't understand why it isn't a good solution to use those function. I will look at Kest.